# How to pick a random number and save it?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a pair card game when the applet starts the cards are face down with the "****" and when a JButton is pressed it puts a figure based on the number picked up randomly, I just want to give the same random number for 2 cards and the figure doesn't have to change every time I press the JButton but I don't know exactly how to do that

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Memorando extends Applet implements ActionListener {
    JButton cartas[];
    JButton juegoNuevo;
    Label marcador;

    public void init(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        Font appletFont=new Font("Monospased", Font.BOLD, 20);
        this.setFont(appletFont);
        juegoNuevo=new JButton("Juego nuevo");
        juegoNuevo.addActionListener(this);
        Panel topPanel=new Panel();
        topPanel.add(juegoNuevo);
        this.add(topPanel,"North");
        cartas=new JButton[8];

        Panel panelCentral=new Panel();
        panelCentral.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
        this.add(panelCentral,"Center");
        marcador=new Label("No has ganado aun :(");
        this.add(marcador,"South");
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            cartas[i]=new JButton("*********");
            cartas[i].addActionListener(this);
        cartas[i].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            panelCentral.add(cartas[i]);
        }
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        JButton boton=(JButton) e.getSource();
        String[] figuras=new String[8];
        figuras[0]="♥";
        figuras[1]="♣";
        figuras[2]="♠";
        figuras[3]="♦";

        if(boton == juegoNuevo){ 
            for(int i=0;i<8;i++){

            cartas[i].setEnabled(true); cartas[i].setLabel("*********");
                 cartas[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
               }

            marcador.setText("Juego nuevo"); 
            juegoNuevo.setEnabled(false);
            return; 

        }
        int random = new Random().nextInt(3)+1;
            if(boton == cartas[0]){
                    cartas[0].setLabel(figuras[random]);
                }
                    if(boton == cartas[1]){
                    int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                            cartas[1].setLabel(figuras[random]);
                        }
                    if(boton == cartas[2]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[2].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[3]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[3].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[4]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[4].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[5]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[5].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[6]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[6].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
                    if(boton == cartas[7]){
                        int numAleatorio=(int) (Math.random()*4);
                                cartas[7].setLabel(figuras[numAleatorio]);
                            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What I mean to save it it's because now every time I click a JButton the figure changes, I need to pick up a number randomly but it has to be static

Comment: If you want to get the same set of random number every time you run your app, set a seed for your random generator.

Comment: My problem is that I'm going to compare the cards, if the figure are not equal in both of them the cards flip back and if they are equal they stay face up that's why I need the number to be repeated only twice

Answer (score 1):

As cricket_007 said, what I'm interpreting is that you want to store the value in a variable. In this case just use code like this `int random = new Random().nextInt(x)+1` where x is the range you want it in (ex. 1 to 100 would be `Random.nextInt(100)+1`)